# Envío de email en Codeigniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

Estoy tratando de hacer una función mail con codeigniter pero no me funciona y no envía al destinatario.

Y los codigos a continuacion

****view****

Ubicado en la carpeta contacto/mailcontacto

```
<form action="emails/enviar" method="post">
<table style="width:80%; margin-left:12%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><table style="width:70%; margin-left:16%; margin-right:16%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label><a >Nombre:</a>   </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td <input type="text"  id="nombre" name="nombre">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:30px"><label><a>Telefono:</a></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="telefono"   name="telefono"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:30px"><label><a">Email:</a></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" ></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p></td>
<td><table style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height:30px"><label><a>Asunto:</a></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"  id="asunto" name="asunto"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><a>Mensaje:</a></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="04" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width:100%; background:#ffffff;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" value="enviar">Enviar</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<? 


defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Emails extends CI_Controller {
function index(){
$datos['titulo'] = 'Envio de Email desde Contacto';
$datos['contenido'] = 'emails';
$this->load->view('contacto/mailcontacto', $datos); // Vista donde esta el formulario dentro dentro de la vista contacto
}
function enviar() {
//Descargar la libreria
$this->load->library('email'); 

//Capturo los imput
$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre'); // capturo los campos del formulario
$telefono = $this->input->post('telefono'); // capturo los campos del formulario
$email = $this->input->post('email'); // capturo los campos del formulario
$email = $this->input->post('asunto'); // capturo los campos del formulario
$mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje'); // capturo los campos del formulario
$this->email->from('emaildedondenvio@dominio.com', 'Contacto' ); //email desde donde envio
$this->email->to('emailadondeseenvia@dominio.com' ); // email a donde envio
$this->email->subject('$nombre'); 
$this->email->subject('$telefono');
$this->email->subject('$email'); 
$this->email->subject('$asunto'); 
$this->email->subject('$mensaje'); 
$this->email->send();
redirect('contacto'); // Se direcciona a la pagina de contacto donde dentro de esta esta la vista emailcontacto dentro de la carpeta contacto
}


   }
```

**archivo mail en config**

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'emailqueenvia@dominio.com'; // correo sin espacio
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'contrasena';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
$config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
?>
```

Agregandole el debut me arroja este error

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 72sm8613915qkc.18 - gsmtp 

hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2607:5300:60:814e::]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 72sm8613915qkc.18 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 1 May 2016 22:58:34 -0430
From: "Contacto" <reserva1@viajandofacil.com>
Return-Path: <reserva1@viajandofacil.com>
To: reserva1@viajandofacil.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?$mensaje?=
Reply-To: "reserva1@viajandofacil.com" <reserva1@viajandofacil.com>
X-Sender: reserva1@viajandofacil.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5726c9624235a
```

Comment: Que librería usas para el envío PHPMailer?

Comment: No he usado esa libreria porque queria comenzar con algo mas sencillo segun entiendo si uso la libreria ci  llamandola $this->load->library("email"); es que puedo enviar.

Comment: Pero me han comentado que es mejor usar phpmailer pero si no se usar lo mas sencillo :(

Comment: Le agregue el debut y me arroja esto

Comment: Coloca el error que te presenta el debug

Comment: Ya he editado y colocado el debug al final de los codigos

Comment: Ese error es por la configuración de la librería, puede ser que no este bien el usuario y contraseña o no tienes activada la opción de enviar correos a través de tu cuenta de gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno viendo el error que colocaste eso se debe a la configuración de seguridad de las cuentas de google, para reparar ese error ingresa a https://myaccount.google.com/security, una vez ahí ve a **Aplicaciones y sitios conectados** y activa el **acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras**.

Te dejo también un ejemplo funcional de como enviar correos con la librería de codeigniter.

```
public function enviar(){
  $config = array(
     'protocol' => 'smtp',
     'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
     'smtp_user' => 'correo@gmail.com', //Su Correo de Gmail Aqui
     'smtp_pass' => 'password', // Su Password de Gmail aqui
     'smtp_port' => '465',
     'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
     'mailtype' => 'html',
     'wordwrap' => TRUE,
     'charset' => 'utf-8'
     );
     $this->load->library('email', $config);
     $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
     $this->email->from('correo@example.com');
     $this->email->subject('Asunto del correo');
     $this->email->message('Hola desde correo');
     $this->email->to('destinatario@example.com');
     if($this->email->send(FALSE)){
         echo "enviado<br/>";
         echo $this->email->print_debugger(array('headers'));
     }else {
         echo "fallo <br/>";
         echo "error: ".$this->email->print_debugger(array('headers'));
     }
}
```

En esa función podrías quitar el debug si devuelve true el if de envío.

Answer (score 1):

si tu instalación de PHP esta sobre un servidor de Windows y IIS puedes configurar IIS 6 para utilizar la función nativa de PHP mail() y si tienes un dominio propio puedes usar tu mismo servidor con [smarterMail](https://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/downloads) que es lo que me tocó hacer a mi para poder enviar emails

[Configurar SMTP Relay en IIS 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t(v=vs.100).aspx)